# Hint allowed function input

Tags: python, annotations

Let's say I have a function that takes either "odd" or "even" as an input parameter. With annotations and mypy/typing I can already hint what the type should be. Is there any way at hinting at the range of allowable values?

```py
from numpy.random import randint

def random(num_t : str='odd'):
    assert num_t in ['odd','even'], "num_t must be either odd or even. Is there a way of annotating this?"
    return randint(100)*2+(1 if num_t == 'odd' else 0)
```

Comment: You could use an enum instead of the string.

Comment: Python3.8 brings the `typing.Literal` type hint.

Comment: Why don't you use a bool?

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat guessing here, but I can use the `typing.Literal` to hint what it should be.

```py
from numpy.random import randint
from typing_extensions import Literal

def random(num_t : Literal['even','odd'] = 'odd'):
    assert num_t in ['odd','even'], "num_t must be either odd or even."
    return randint(100)*2+(1 if num_t == 'odd' else 0)
```